# Self signed certificate using own CA not working on intranet

Tags: certificate, openssl, iis, intranet

I have made a CA and generated a self-signed certificate signed using that CA after that I bind it with my local website on IIS server works fine on my PC, but when I access it on other PC on the same intranet than it gives a error of unknown publisher. What I want to achieve is that , I should be able to access the locally hosted website on IIS server on https on the intranet.

[image: error]

Comment: What happens when you accept the risk and continue?

Comment: Have you actually imported the custom CA to this other machine as a "trusted CA"?

Comment: @u1686_grawity i did this and it worked , but does this mean that I have to install custom CA on every machine on intranet , what about mobile devices and iphones ?

Comment: Yes, it actually means that. Certificates don't just start working because they were signed by _a_ CA – that only happens with specific CAs that the devices _trust_ to issue certs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deploy the CA certificate to all clients that want to connect.

Certificates don't just start working because they were signed by *a* CA – that only happens with specific CAs that the devices **trust** to issue certificates truthfully. (If that weren't the case, anyone could start issuing their own certificates for websites they don't own, and that would completely defeat the point of certificates!)

So you will need to manually install the CA root certificate everywhere. For your own smartphones that's not a problem – both Android and iOS allow custom CA installation. (For iOS, I think you need to send the .crt file as an attachment via email, then open it through the built-in iOS Mail app.)

You still have gained an advantage, in that you will only need to deploy **one** certificate – the CA root cert – and not many different certificates for various HTTPS services you might have in the future. As long as the devices have the CA installed, they'll automatically recognize all future certs issued by it.

Though I wouldn't recommend doing this for a website that your employees, family, or various random visitors need to access; telling them to install your CA would be asking to place a *huge* amount of trust in you. So instead you should set up a domain name for your web app (yes, even if it's internal-only), and then get a certificate from *Let's Encrypt* or some other public CA (yes, you can do ACME on Windows).

---

(As a side note, in the technical meaning of the term, if the certificate has been issued by a CA then it's by definition *not* "self-signed".)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure that you are not using SHA1 algorithm for generating Self-Signed Certs from IIS, since it is obsolete in modern browsers. If it is SHA1 algo, use better algos like SHA256.

After that, export your certificate with only Public key. Add it to Windows Certificate Store on every Windows machine through which you want to access your local website over the intranet. For Firefox, you will have to add the Certificate in Firefox's own certificate store.

If you will not add Certificate on every machine, then they won't be able to trust your site. Your browser only trust your site if the CA is already present in the Certificate store it is using.

If you do not want to manually add your Certificate on every machine on your intranet, you can go for trusted Certificate providers. There are a lot who provide Certificates for free. I personally prefer Let's Encrypt. For installing and renewing Certificates automatically on IIS, you can use win-acme.

Ref: https://github.com/win-acme/win-acme

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641473/trust-a-self-signed-cert-from-iis

You can refer to the above link as it is quite similar to your issue.